# Is a 1 Hz signal the same as 1 PPS one?

Tags: frequency, time

Is a 1 Hz signal output from a ripple counter or divider the same as  a formal "1 PPS" signal? If no, what is the difference in the time domain?

Comment: "PPS" is more specific than "Hz." It stands for "pulses per second," and while you can use "Hz" or "Hertz" to describe the frequency of any periodic signal, not all periodic signals can be described as having "pulses."

Comment: What do you need to caracterize a signal ? Only a frequency ? If so, 1hz and one PPs is the same. But what about the shape of the pulse/signal ? You could have a sine, a square, triangle, pulses of 10us, pulses of 10ms and so on.

Comment: You may also come across "cps" or cycles-per-second. And kilo-cycles and mega-cycles.

Comment: @rdtsc I even came across kMcps for a deprecated version of GHz in an old paper 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both signals will have a rising edge, and a falling edge, every second.

However, their name tends to imply different things about the duty cycle.

1 PPS implies 'pulses', with likely a low duty cycle.

The GPS '1 PPS' signal is a 20 us, with the leading edge coincident with the whole second mark. The GNSS '1 PPS' is 36 us, similarly aligned. There are quite a few other applications that specify 1 PPS with other parameters.

A '1 Hz', depending on how it has been made, could be 50% duty cycle, if the last divider in the chain is a /2. If it's the carry-out from a /10 stage, it may have a 10% duty cycle. If it's the 'D' output (2<sup>3</sup> weight) from a /10, then it would be 20%. There's no limit (beyond the period of the divider input clock) to the duty cycle that ingenuity could create.

Comment: Without further definition, a 1 PPS signal could just have one pulse each second, without defining the relation of the pulse start within the seconds, as long as the average is 1 pulse per second, and there is exactly 1 pulse within a time frame or each second.

Comment: how can be the 1Hz manipulated in order to become a pulse of 20us for example, without using a microcontroller?

Comment: @Ken90 it depends whether you want the 20 us to be +/- 1 us, or +/- 1 ps. If us accuracy, then a monostable like the HC123 triggered on the leading edge will do it. If ps accuracy, then starting from a 10 MHz clock, divide down to seconds with HC163/393 type dividers, gating the last stages to give you 20 us. Not everything has to be done with a MCU.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks a lot for this suggestion. Yes I don't want to use a MCU indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the definition.

Both are signals with some relation to 1 Hz or to 1 second.

A 1 Hz signal from a ripple counter would generally be a square wave with 50% duty.

And a PPS signal would have one pulse per second - which is arbitrary.

Without further definition of the signal, a 1 Hz square wave with 50% duty will fit into definition of a signal having one pulse per second. It would have a rising edge every second, and high level with duration of 0.5 seconds, a falling edge, and low level with duration of 0.5 seconds.

But generally, a PPS signal would usually have just a short pulse once per second. And it does not even define anything else about it. It could just have one pulse each second, without defining how short or long the pulse is, and how much time there will be between pulses.

For a GPS application, a PPS signal would mean that each pulse defines a start of a new second so the pulses start with a period of 1 second, and the pulses may have some defined length like 0.1 seconds, but the length usually does not matter very much.